Clean Architecture and Fused Location Provider
I am trying to integrate com.google.android.gms.location library into my project which is heavily focused on Clean Architecure.
I understand how things come together in the data layer and how I can push back location data through domain into the presentation but I would like to use this function also:
settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest)

The problem is with the addOnFailureListener branch: ResolvableApiException retruns with a PendingIntent which should be passed to a registerForActivityResult but all these things are in the data layer.
I cannot pass back the Intent as an Any object to the domain then cast it back because it feels like cheating.
As far as I know I cant really do the same to show a notification to turn on the location on the app and after pressing yes it will do so (like in google maps).
So far the code
class LocationTracking @Inject constructor(
    private val fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient,
    private val settingsClient: SettingsClient,
    private val locationManager: LocationManager?,
) : LocationTracking {

    override suspend fun isLocationTrackingReady() = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                continuation.resume(Result.Success(true))
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                val isGpsEnabled =
                    locationManager?.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ?: false

                val isNetworkEnabled =
                    locationManager?.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) ?: false

                if (it is ResolvableApiException) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "LOG ${it.resolution}")
                }

                continuation.resumeWithException(it)
            }
    }


    private companion object {
        private val locationRequest = LocationRequest.Builder(
            Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY,
            2000L
        ).build()

        private val locationSettingsRequest = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
            .build()
    }

}

The domain layer shoudld not include the google library
The architecture is the most common
presentation (android) -> domain (kotlin) <- data (android)
Should I give back the result as Exception and have it casted back to ResolvableApiException in the ViewModel? It also feels like a hit on the Clean Arch.
Or should I duplicate the LocationRequest, have both of the same copy in locator:data and locator:presentation so in data it can be used for the client.requestLocationUpdates(request, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper()) and on a presentation level thing the checking and the intent.
